# Collecting performance and runtime metrics in cpp

Tags: gratis, c++, go

I am aware that go language has an excellent support for collecting metric data. We can visualize the data in any manner we want using handy tools like [go-metrics](https://godoc.org/github.com/armon/go-metrics) and [influxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/).

I have a CPP application (similar to bitcoin) and looking for an easy way to collect some metrics. Can any CPP developer recommend anything you are aware of?

I am looking for something available for free (opensource or available for free trials). My operating system is **Linux**. I will be collecting all the packet latency in the network (Example PING-PONG time between two nodes over a socket) along with outbound/inbound data traffic

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Updated the question with more specific details

Comment: Thanks for the update! So do I understand correctly you either need a stand-alone Linux application or a c++ library to include with your application?

Comment: Yes I need a cpp library which must be similar to what go-metric/influxDB provides in go.

Comment: Imagine people might not know go-metric/influxDB. Does your question include sufficient details then? Don't blame answerers if they do not offer details you haven't asked for then ;) Again, see: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and cross-check. I won't annoy you any further now, everything else is up to you :) Good luck!